# Two definitions of one set being dense in the other

Tags: general-topology

Assume $\langle X,\mathscr{O}\rangle$ is a topological space. Let $A,S\subseteq X$. Let $\langle S,\mathscr{O}\rangle$ be a subspace of $X$ with $\mathrm{Cl}_S$ being its closure operation.

There are two definitions of $A$ being dense in $S$:

1. $A$ is dense in $S$ iff $A$ is dense in $\langle S,\mathscr{O}\rangle$ iff $\mathrm{Cl}_S\,(A\cap S)=S$
2. $A$ is dense is $S$ iff $S\subseteq\mathrm{Cl}\,A$.

By elementary porperties of subspaces we have:
$$
\mathrm{Cl}_S\,(A\cap S)=S\longleftrightarrow\mathrm{Cl}\,(A\cap S)\cap S=S\longleftrightarrow S\subseteq \mathrm{Cl}\,(A\cap S)
$$
In answers to both these questions: [the first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/understanding-the-definition-of-dense-sets) and [the second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58190/understanding-of-nowhere-dense-sets?lq=1), the following equivalence is referred to:
$$S\subseteq \mathrm{Cl}\,(A\cap S)\longleftrightarrow S\subseteq\mathrm{Cl}\,A$$
in order to establish equivalence between 1 and 2. Yet simple counterexample shows that the implication from right to left is false: take the set of reals with the standard order topology and put $S=\{1\}$ and $A=(0,1)$.

EDIT: The sets may even have a non-empty intersection: put $S=\{\frac{1}{2},1\}$ and the rest as in the example above.

My question is: what am I missing from the picture to see that 1 and 2 are indeed equivalent?

Comment: For $A \subset S$, the two are equivalent.

Comment: OK, but neither of the definitions requires it. That is the point.

Comment: Right, it's just how the idea might arise. People apparently tend to think of subsets of $S$ when the words "dense in $S$" occur.

Comment: Possibly nicer counterexample, $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}\subseteq\operatorname{Cl}(\Bbb Q)$ when considering the real numbers with the standard topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your counterexample is correct. Note that the [answer to your second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58204/43949) has a comment that gives a similar counterexample. I think the equivalence is wrong.

There is a bit of ambiguity in the definition of denseness. In most cases (see the first link as well as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set)), **$A$ is assumed to be a subset of $S$** and I suspect that the source of your second definition assumes this condition (in which case both definitions are clearly equivalent).

I haven't encountered cases where this terminology is used when $A$ is not necessarily a subset of $S$, but if you do, just use the definition given in whatever context you're in. Your first definition is a reasonable generalization: if $A \not\subset S$, then $A$ is defined to be dense in $S$ if $A \cap S$ is dense in $S$ (in the sense of the second definition).

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are not equivalent. Your counterexample S={1} and A =(0,1) shows that: it satisfies 2 but not 1.

Comment: Well, indeed :) But "missing from the picture" I thought about possible additional assumptions (except from the obvious one that $A$ is a subset of $S$) in which the equivalence holds.